# currentregion.copy and destination stopper

Tags: excel, vba

I have a snippet of code

```
For Each wkSht In Sheets

    If Sheet6.Range("E3").Value = wkSht.Name Then
    wkSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Sheet6.Range("A12")
    End If    
Next
```

need to modify this so that when copied to sheet6, it will not copy anything over row 200 and below. so in the event the currentregion is >= 187 rows, it will not copy/paste anything past that. Done some googling and can't find any solution to this

Comment: the need is pretty much a fail safe so that the sheet copied is not accidently pasted over crucial data/formulas that are found in row 200 and below on sheet6. side note: I cannot move this table without completely reworking 9 modules worth of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code to what is below. Your post is a bit confusing because first you say below 200, then 187. Whatever you need can be placed in the rows argument of the `Resize` method.

```
Dim CopySheet as Worksheet
CopySheet = Worksheets(Sheet6.Range("E3").Value))

With CopySheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .Resize(186,.Columns.Count).Copy Destination:=Sheet6.Range("A12")
End With
```

Comment: well the data is pasted starting in cell A12. so 200 rows - the 12 it doesn't use = 188...a 1 row cushion would be 187 rows...I should have explained that first sorry